# Создание копии на указатель

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Как можно скопировать из указателя на int в новую переменную, пытаюсь

```
int *wordC = new int[length + 2];
int *сopy = new int[length + 2];
copy(wordС, wordС, сopy);
```

в таком подходе на выходе массив copy остается с таким же мусором.
Второй вопрос, почти про тоже самое, есть

```
char* file = new char[length];
```

нужно file скопировать только часть, к примеру с 10 до 16 позиции(в рантайме только становится известно откуда и сколько копировать) в новый массив

Comment: Откуда берётся функция copy? Похоже, её имя перекрывается именем нового указателя.

Comment: Вы создали один массив с мусором, второй, *неверно пытаетесь* скопировать один массив во второй, получаете мусор - и еще и удивляетесь?... Копируйте хотя бы верно - типа `std::copy(wordC,wordC+length+2,copy)`, если уж так хочется копировать мусор :) И не устраивайте коллизию имен!!

Comment: @mymedia нашел пример в интернете, _OutIt copy(_InIt _First, _InIt _Last, _OutIt _Dest) вот его определение. Я новичок пришел из Java

Comment: @harry по определению выше я копирую в Dest, то есть в copy, туда куда я хочу

Comment: Ну и прочему вы передаете как _Last - тот же _First? _Last - это в данном случае указатель на элемент **за** последним.

Comment: Примерно так: `int length = 10;
    int *src = new int[length];
    int *dst = new int[length];
    std::copy(src, src+length, dst);` И еще - "*копия на указатель*" - это вообще непонятно что...

Comment: Понял, получается я передаю указатель а не индекс

Comment: "копия на указатель  а как правильно сказать?

Comment: Копия указателя будет `int * p_сopy{wordC};`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для копирования элементов одного контейнера (массива) в другой контейнер (массив)  можно использовать стандартный алгоритм `std::copy`, который объявлен в заголовке `<algorithm>`.

Например,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 10;
    int *src = new int[N];

    size_t pos = 3;
    size_t n = 5;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) src[pos + i] = i;

    int *dsn = new int[N];

    std::copy( src + pos, src + pos + n, dsn + pos );
    // или если нужно скопировать в начало массива dsn, то
    // std::copy( src + pos, src + pos + n, dsn );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) std::cout << dsn[pos + i] << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    delete [] dsn;
    delete [] src;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
0 1 2 3 4
```

Первые два параметра алгоритма `std::copy` задают диапазон копируемых элементов исходного контейнера. Например, это может быть указатель на первый элемент копируемого диапазона элементов массива и указатель на элемент следующий за последним копируемым элементом диапазона. 
Последний параметр алгоритма указывает место контейнера назначения, куда будут копироваться элементы. Для массивов это может быть указатель на элемент массива, с которого начнется запись элементов исходного массива.